# Check when user calls a certain number Call Kit

Tags: swift, callkit

I am trying to use call kit or another library to check when a user calls a certain number. I want to know when this happens so that I can send the user a notification. I know that you can detect incoming calls but not sure if outgoing calls are allowed. Is there any way for me to do this?
Thanks in advance